Williams Fractals 3bars only with low and median low
I'm using the Williams Fractals Indicator with a 3-bar setup to identify lows only. Additionally, I have a custom criterion that I call "median lows" . According to this rule, if I detect 3 lows using the Williams criterion, and the middle low is lower than the other two, I consider it a "median low"(low 2 wih arrow on screenshot).
Median Low Example
I tried coding this logic, but during debugging, I noticed that the plot for what should be the median low is being plotted on the third low (low number 3 that is the trigger of median low) instead of the second one (low number 2 / arrow low), as shown in the screenshot. I think there's a memory issue within the array because if I change the values from min_low_3 to min_low_2/1 in the plotshape line, the plot position doesn't change.
//@version=5
indicator('Median Low Williams Fractal', shorttitle='Median Fractals', overlay=true)

// Input and global variables
n = input.int(title='Periods', defval=200, minval=2)
a = 2

//Down Fractal
minS = low[a] < low[a-1] and low[a] < low[a+1]

// Array to store short-term lows
var float[] short_lows = array.new_float(0)

// Add the short-term low to the array if identified
if minS
    array.push(short_lows, low[a])

// Keep only the last 3 short-term lows in the array
if array.size(short_lows) > 3
    array.shift(short_lows)

// Variables to plot the short and median lows
var bool isMedianLowFound = false
var float medianLowValue = na

// Check if the central short-term low is lower than the other two (median logic)
if array.size(short_lows) == 3
    min_low_1 = array.get(short_lows, 0)
    min_low_2 = array.get(short_lows, 1)
    min_low_3 = array.get(short_lows, 2)
    
    // If the second short-term low is lower than the other two
    if min_low_2 < min_low_1 and min_low_2 < min_low_3
        isMedianLowFound := true
        medianLowValue := min_low_3
        // Reset the array of short-term lows
        array.clear(short_lows)
    else
        // Do not reset if no median low is found
        isMedianLowFound := false
        medianLowValue := na

// Plot short-term lows (green) only if no median low has been found
plotshape(series=(minS and not isMedianLowFound) ? low[a] : na, title="Short-term Low", location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, offset=-2)

// Plot the median low (blue) only for median low
plotshape(series=isMedianLowFound ? medianLowValue : na, title="Median Low", location=location.belowbar, color=color.blue, style=shape.triangleup, size=size.small, offset=-2)

// Reset the median low condition if a new short-term low occurs
if minS
    isMedianLowFound := false

